# orWhere returns always true

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-query-builder, laravel-middleware

I want to hide a div that only shows for the users with the role "admin" or "writer", doesn't need to be both, using a variable *$check*  that becomes true if the user has one of these roles, so i tried to do it using the following logic in the view controller :

```
 public function index(){
    $check = false;
    if(auth()->user() != null){
        $check = auth()->user()->roles()
                    ->where('name', 'admin')
                    ->orWhere('name','writer')
                    ->exists();
        dd(auth()->user()->roles()->Where('name','writer')->exists());
        // dd($check);
    }
    return view('albums.index', [
            'albums'    => Album::latest()->filter(request(['tag','search','label','date']))->paginate(6),
            'check'     => $check,
        ]);
}
```

the problem is that the variable *$check* always returns true for every single user, I removed the orWhere() part of the query and it became turned back to false the way it was supposed to be, I thought maybe somehow the users were getting the 'writer' role by default despite it not showing on the pivot table of the Role User modules, so i did a quick dump and die to be sure and it returned false

[image: dump and die with role 'writer']

I made sure that *OrWhere()* is what's causing this using other DDs,
I checked the documentation and I think I got the syntax of the query right?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use this query:

```
 public function index(){
    $check = false;
    if(auth()->user() != null){
        $check = auth()->user()->roles()
        ->where(function($query){
            $query->where('name','admin');
            $query->where('name', '!=','writer');
        })
        ->orWhere(function($query){
            $query->where('name', '!=','admin');
            $query->where('name','writer');
        })->exists();
        dd($check);
    }
    return view('albums.index', [
            'albums'    => Album::latest()->filter(request(['tag','search','label','date']))->paginate(6),
            'check'     => $check,
        ]);
}
```

Comment: same issue, it still returns true whilst i'm logged on with a user that is neither an admin or a writer

Comment: Can you please dd the logged in user's roles with: dd(auth()->user()->roles); and show me the output

Comment: Maybe `->whereIn('name', ['admin', 'writer'])` might be what you're looking for?